# Is it possible to map a spring data entity field to another field in elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have this model:

```
public class Foo{
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    String color;
}
```

right now it maps to the field "color" in elasticsearch document. Can I map it to another field: "shirtColor"? Maybe through an annotation?

Answer (score 0):

spring-data-elasticsearch uses Jackson Object Mapper to serialize the POJO into json. You can use `@JsonProperty` attribute if you want to change the name of field which is store in Elastic Search.

```
public class Foo{
   @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
   @JsonProperty("shirtColor")
   String color;
}
```

However you will loose the benefit of using `findBy*` methods while querying the data back from elastic search and you will have to write your own custom queries to fetch the data.